# Border around legend in form does not show

Tags: codeigniter, border, legend, fieldset

I have a simple CodeIgniter view that simply refuses to show the border around the form even though I have used the fieldset and legend tags.

I don't believe the CSS is overriding this anywhere but at this point I don't even know how to check (a fairly large CSS split over multiple files if this statement is true).

Here's the simple HTML. Help!

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Log In</legend>
<?php

echo form_open('form/login');
echo form_input('email', set_value('email', 'Email'));
echo form_password('password', set_value('password', 'Password'));
echo form_submit('submit', 'Log In');
echo form_close();

?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I wanted to take a second to give you a high-five (and a +1) for submitting a well formatted post as your first question. :) (You'd be surprized how rare this is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your html is *not valid*.

The `<fieldset>` tags go **inside** your `<form>`

```
<?=form_open('form/login');?>
<fieldset>
   <legend>Log In</legend>
   <?
     echo form_input('email', set_value('email', 'Email'));
     echo form_password('password', set_value('password', 'Password'));
     echo form_submit('submit', 'Log In');
   ?>
</fieldset>
<?=form_close();?>
```

**If this does not fix it for you** *(which I imagine it will)*:

Using [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) or [Firebug Extension for Firefox](http://www.getfirebug.com/) you can *inspect an element* on your page by right clicking on it and chosing `Inspect Element`. This will bring you to the dom explorer and you'll be able to see all CSS Syles being applied to an object and where they are coming from. This should help you narrow down a CSS style that might be overriding the default visuals. (And confirm/deny the existance of such a conflict).

Comment: Thank you Aren. Placing the fieldset inside the form did not do it, however using Firebug I was able to track down the culprit in the template's reset.css file where the fieldset border was being zeroed out. Deleted the reference to fieldset in reset.css and borders are now showing.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than deleting it in the reset you should load reset first then override that in your bespoke CSS.  If you start messing with the reset you might give yourself problems later